# Why doesn't the share operator prevent an observable firing twice?

Tags: rxjs

I have the following operators:

```
  const prepare = (value$: Observable<string>) =>
    value$.pipe(tap((x) => console.log("remove: ", x)), share());

  const performTaskA = (removed$: Observable<string>) =>
    removed$.pipe(tap((x) => console.log("pathA: ", x)),);

  const performTaskB = (removed$: Observable<string>) =>
    removed$.pipe(tap((x) => console.log("pathB: ", x)));
```

and I call them like this:

```
  const prepared$ = value$.pipe(prepare);
  const taskADone$ = prepared$.pipe(performTaskA);
  const taskBDone$ = prepared$.pipe(performTaskB);

  merge(taskADone$, taskBDone$).subscribe();
```

Due to the `share` in `prepare` I would expect 'remove' to be logged only once, however it appears twice.

Why is this not working?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-remove-fires-twice-iyk12?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: I think you want `shareReplay(1)` instead of `share`

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because your source Observable is `of()` that just emits one `next` notification and then `complete`. Everything in RxJS in synchronous unless you work with time or you intentionally make your code asynchronous (eg. with `Promise.resolve` or with `asyncScheduler`).

In your demo, `share()` receives one `next` and one `complete` notification immediately which makes its internal state to reset. It will also unsubscribe from its source Obserable because there are no more observers (the second source `taskBDone$` you're merging has not subscribed yet). Then `taskBDone$` is merged into the chain and `share()` creates internally a new instance of `Subject` and the whole process repeats.

These are the relevant parts in `share()`:

- Dispose handler triggered after receiving `complete` from source https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L120
- New Subject created: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L113
- `share()` resets its state https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts#L163

So if your sources are going to be synchronous you should better use `shareReplay()` (instead of `share()`) that will just replay the entire sequence of events to every new observer.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jawajw?devtoolsheight=60

Notice, that in your demo if you used `of("TEST").pipe(delay(0))` as your source Observable it would work as you expected because `delay(0)` would force asynchronous behavior and both source Observables would first subscribe and then in another JavaScript frame would emit their `next` and `complete`.